# Air quality in all cities in the USA

Tags: usa, city, environment

Where can I find information about pollution or air quality by city in U.S.? I would like to the data to be from an official source.

Comment: Have you looked at [catalog.data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=air+quality&sort=views_recent+desc&tags=air-quality)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Environmental Protection Agency monitors this in many places and have much of this data available for free, as well as extensive documentation: https://www.epa.gov/outdoor-air-quality-data